# Add "Order Status" option to Amazon Checkout for Magento

Tags: php, html, xml, magento, amazon-web-services

I am using "Pay with Amazon Checkout" for Magento and running Magento 1.8.1 CE

[Amazon Checkout for Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pay-with-amazon-advanced-payment-apis-for-europe.html)

The only option that is provided by the developer is to set the order status to "processing" but I would like to add another status that I created called "Processed through Amazon" that gives the order a status of "closed" or "complete"

I want to do this because if we don't, the system we use to pull all order information from every ecommerce store my company has setup, will see the order twice: **once on our website, and once on amazon.**

Has anyone used this extension or can you download/install it to see if you can find a way to add options to the "drop down" in the ***Admin > System > Configuration > CreativeStyle > Amazon Payments > General Settings > Order Status on Authorization***

Thank you so much for any help you guys/gals provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend the Amazon payment module to include another order status for that dropdown (involves changing the xml files that control the adminhtml).

Take a look at this custom extension- you can modify the Observer.php file to look for the Amazon payment method and then set the appropriate order status.

[MAGENTO AUTO INVOICE AND SET CUSTOM ORDER STATUS UPON CHECKOUT](http://www.atwix.com/magento/auto-invoice-and-custom-order-status-upon-checkout/)

Comment: Awesome. I'll look over this in the morning :)